# React-native - ios - Enoent - No such file or directory found

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native, native

I'm building an app in react-native for ios.  When attempting to build, xcode reports no errors and the simulator starts up.  The app begins to load and I get a red error screen with the following info in the log:

> 2017-03-20 19:22:40.523325 [APPNAME][69099:5420843] []
>   nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
>   2017-03-20 19:22:40.541 [fatal][tid:main] TransformError:
>   /Users/[NAME]/[COMPANY]/dev/[APPNAME]/node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/index.js:
>   ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/[NAME]/[COMPANY]/dev/[APPNAME]/node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/package.json'
>   2017-03-20 19:22:40.549905 [APPNAME][69099:5420846] []
>   nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28

Have tried the following to fix:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -fr $TMPDIR/npm*
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf * (in /users/name/developer/xcode/deriveddata/
npm install
react-native upgrade
```

Also re-install react-native, react-native-cli

Also updated node to newest version

Also reinstalled xcode

Comment: Have you tried closing the packager in the terminal and re-run?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: 8.2.1 (8C1002), though got some momentum with clearing the packager cache and reinstalling dependencies in npm... Got another problem, but going to post about it on Matt Aft's comment regarding the packager.

Comment: This put me on a good path.  Thanks Matt.  Closing packager and re-running didn't do it, but clearing the packager cache showed a lot of conflicts between dependencies.  Fixing those, clearing cache, reinstalling node_modules, clearing the xcode cache in ~/library/developer/xcode/deriveddata and /var/folders *inhale* fixed the immediate problem.. but now I have another issue that'll post in another ticket.  Thanks again Matt!

Answer (score 0):

User Matt Aft pointed me in the right direction with a question around the packager.  Here's the solution that was in a comment to his comment (for anyone suffering this problem and needing a solution):

This put me on a good path. Thanks Matt. Closing packager and re-running didn't do it, but clearing the packager cache showed a lot of conflicts between dependencies. Fixing those, clearing cache, reinstalling node_modules, clearing the xcode cache in ~/library/developer/xcode/deriveddata and /var/folders inhale fixed the immediate problem.. but now I have another issue that'll post in another ticket. Thanks again Matt! –

Comment: How do you close the packager in the terminal exactly as Matt Aft suggests?

Answer (score 0):

The application is expecting a file at

> /Users/[NAME]/[COMPANY]/dev/[APPNAME]/node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/index.js

but that file does not exist (which is what ENOENT means). So you either have to create the expected directory structure or else configure your application such that it looks in the correct directory.